# One of the OSB node has high response time

Tags: osb

We have two osb nodes in cluster.  One of node osb1 has less ovearall response time ( 1 sec) when measured in appdynamics,  another  node osb2 has high response(20sec). We brought down each of this node and tested individually. We see same behavior.  Any suggestions on what to look into to identify the issue.?  The osb configuration across both the nodes Is identical and jvm configuration also identical. Heap usage is same. CPU bit differs.

Comment: One of the things to look at is the network latency and how it is responding in each node.

Comment: Are these on the same managed server? Do they follow the same network route? Are you doing any heavy transformations or Call Outs?